# Why does the iteration speed increase over time? [JAVA]

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was playing around with loops in java, when I saw that the iteration speed keeps increasing.

Kind of seemed interesting.

Any ideas why?

Code:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class RandomStuffTest {

    public static long iterationsPerSecond = 0;

    @Test
    void testIterationSpeed() {
        Thread t = new Thread(()->{
            try{
                while (true){
                    System.out.println("Iterations per second: "+iterationsPerSecond);
                    iterationsPerSecond = 0;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

        while (true){
            for (long i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                iterationsPerSecond++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Iterations per second: 6111
Iterations per second: 2199824206
Iterations per second: 4539572003
Iterations per second: 6919540856
Iterations per second: 9442209284
Iterations per second: 11899448226
Iterations per second: 14313220638
Iterations per second: 16827637088
Iterations per second: 19322118707
Iterations per second: 21807781722
Iterations per second: 24256315314
Iterations per second: 26641505580
```

Another thing that I noticed:

The CPU usage was around 20% all the time and not really increasing...

Maybe because I was running the code as a test using Junit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the Java Memory Model (JMM).

Every thread is allowed to have (does not have to do this) a local copy of each field. Whenever it writes or reads this field it is free to just set its local copy and sync it up with other threads' local copies much, much later.

Said differently, the JVM is free to re-order instructions, do things in parallel, and otherwise apply whatever weird stuff it wants to optimize your code, *as long as* certain guarantees are never broken.

One guarantee that is easy to understand: The JVM is free to reorder or parallelize 2 sequential instructions, **but it must never be possible to write code that can observe this except through timing**.

In other words, `int x = 0; x = 5; System.out.println(x);` must necessarily print 5 and never 0.

You can establish such relationships between 2 threads as well but this involves the use of `volatile` and/or `synchronized` and/or something that does this internally (most things in the `java.util.concurrent` package).

You didn't, so this result is meaningless. Most likely, the instruction `iterationsPerSecond = 0` is having no effect; the code `iterationsPerSecond++` reads `9442209284`, increments by one, and writes it back - and that field got written to 0 someplace in the middle of all that, which thus accomplished nothing whatsoever.

If you want to test this properly, try a `volatile` variable, or better yet an `AtomicLong`.

Comment: I tested the same code with the only difference leaving a small interval of some milliseconds between each iteration and then it gave me correct results.

Comment: In fact, if you run the original code it long enough, you will probably observe it resetting at some point, randomly, as the zeroing comes in at just the right time.

Comment: I tried it with volatile, but still same result :/

Comment: @rzwitserloot With AtomicLong it works as expected, but I think that it has a greater impact on performance?

Comment: @OsirisTeam we're talking about memory models and concurrency 'it worked, this once, right now, on this machine' is no guarantee of anything much. Yes, there is overhead involved in sharing data between 2 threads; quite a bit of it. That is the point. If you don't want it, then restrict the printing of progress on the iteration to the thread that is doing the iterations; there is no 'easy, performance-impact-free' way to share mutating data between threads. `volatile` does not make `++` atomic, so, that was my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Like already indicated, the code is broken due to a data race.

The JIT can do some funny stuff with your code because of the data race:

```
    while (true){
        for (long i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            iterationsPerSecond++;
        }
    }
```

Since it doesn't know that another thread is also messing with the iterationsPerSecond, the compiler could fold the for loop because it can calculate the outcome of the loop:

```
    while (true){
        iterationsPerSecond=Long.MAX_VALUE
    }
```

And it could even decide to pull out the write of the loop since the same value is written (loop invariant code motion):

```
    iterationsPerSecond=Long.MAX_VALUE
    while (true){    
    }
```

It could even decide the throw away the store, because it doesn't know there are any readers. So effectively it is a dead store and hence it can apply dead code elimination.

```
    while (true){    
    }
```

An atomic or volatile would solve the problem because a happens before edge is established. Using a volatile or an atomiclong.get/set is equally expensive. It has the same compiler restrictions and fences on hardware level.

If you want to run microbenchmarks, I would suggest checking out JMH. It will protect you against a lot of trivial mistakes.